# Segmentation Fault in libgnustl_shared.so in Android

Tags: android, c++, c, debugging

I'm running an  executable in Android. The exe uses a number of shared libraries which are written in both C and C++.

I need some help on how to start debugging the following error:

> interfaces[3274]: segfault at f22bacfc ip  sp 
>   error 7 in libgnustl_shared.so[f4266000+ed000]

interfaces: is the binary exectutable
Any tool I can used to debug this? Please share the steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gdb to debug the android executable.

From [this](http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/debugging_gdb.html) page:

> 1. First you need to run gdbserver on the device:
>      `$ gdbserver :5039 /system/bin/executable`
> 2. The `:5039` tells `gdbserver` to listen on port 5039 on the localhost,
>      which `adb` bridges from the host to the device. executable represents
>      the command to debug, a common one being runtime `-s` which starts the
>      entire system all running in a single process. 
>      Launch gdb on the desktop. This can be done easily with the following
>      command in the shell from which you built:
>      `$ gdbclient executable`

Comment: Thanks Mohit:) A quick question : ADB is not enabled on my device, I'm connecting through serial port via putty.. what change  should I do? how do I get the port on which putty is connected?

Comment: After gdb my best bet would be logs. Looking at the name `libgnustl_shared` it appears some stl container is used incorrectly. Targetting `C++` files or stripping off some `C++` modules temporarily can give some insight.